# What does the -d flag stand for when running Flutter Build_Runner?

Tags: flutter, flutter-freezed

We use a lot of freezed packages and utilize them with json serializable stuff in a project. The command we use to auto generate is:

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch -d
```

I can't remember why I needed to use the -d command line option, but I remember that it wasn't working properly without it. What I want to know is what does the `-d` actually do? I haven't been able to find what its function is.

EDIT: I actually found the answer running `flutter pub run build_runner --help` and I found that `-d` is just shorthand for the command line option `--delete-conflicting-outputs`

Answer (score 0):

The -d option is to help target the device such as flutter run -d <device_id>.

Citation found here -> https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli

Comment: Granted .. you aren' t specifying an ID to target it to,  so I am not sure why you would run it without specifying the target device ID unless its assume and inhereted elsewhere perhaps?